# that brother of Jane who is

Tags: possessives, attachment-ambiguity

> a. I am talking about **the** brother of Jane who is a doctor.
>
> b. I am talking about **that** brother of Jane who is a doctor.
>
> c. I am talking about **the** brother of Jane, who is a doctor.
>
> d. I am talking about **that** brother of Jane, who is a doctor.

In which case (1) Jane is a doctor, and in which case (2) Jane's brother is a doctor, are all of the above sentences grammatically correct?

Comment: All of them are grammatically correct.  All of them are ambiguous about who is a doctor, although the versions with *that* sound a little more like the brother is a doctor.  If you really wanted to be clear, you'd have to say something like "Jane's brother who is a doctor."

Comment: I read all of them to be the brother who is a doctor, as I read "who is a doctor" to be qualifying the unknown, and Jane is a known. for it to be Jane i would write "I am talking about the brother of jane the doctor."